# invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’ when building NFIQ2

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the source from https://github.com/usnistgov/NFIQ2. Followed the instructions but keep running in the following error during 'make'.

```
    src/wsq/delfet.cpp:86:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘        char*’ [-fpermissive]
       fet->names[fet->num-1] = '\0';
                        ^~~~
    src/wsq/delfet.cpp:87:29: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to
    ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
      fet->values[fet->num-1] = '\0';
                         ^~~~
    src/wsq/delfet.cpp: In function ‘int deletefet_ret(char*, FET*)’:
    src/wsq/delfet.cpp:111:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to         ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
       fet->names[fet->num-1] = '\0';
                        ^~~~
    src/wsq/delfet.cpp:112:29: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to         ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
       fet->values[fet->num-1] = '\0';
                         ^~~~
```

As far as I can see it seems to come from the src/wsq/delfet.o file.

```
    fet->names[fet->num-1] = '\0';
    fet->values[fet->num-1] = '\0';
```

Any idea why this is going wrong here and how to fix this?

Comment: Given the file extension, this appears to be C++.  Why is the question tagged `c`?

Comment: Please add the declaration of `fet` and the declaration of its type.

Comment: We don't debug third-party applications. You should either raise this with the developer, or narrow the problem to a [mcve] then ask.

Comment: Badly written code, possibly it should be `fet->names[fet->num-1] = nullptr;` etc.

Comment: `int main() { char *ptr = '\0'; }` is invalid now in C++...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Can you provide some citation for this claim?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wish.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Looks like [C++11 changed it just enough](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL)

Comment: To make your question more useful you should include details about your operating system and compiler

Answer (score 4):

[The code is broken](https://github.com/usnistgov/NFIQ2/issues/37) because it (probably mistakenly) tries to use `'\0'` as a "null pointer constant" during this assignment to `char*`.

Trouble is, that was always silly, and C++11 banned it. Null pointer constants are now either `nullptr` or integer literals (`char`s don't count).

Per the linked bug thread, this will need a fix from the authors, but the upstream repo has already changed the code to, for example:

```
fet->names[fet->num-1] = NULL;
fet->values[fet->num-1] = NULL;
```

So, you could make the same change.

Alternatively, force C++03 mode in your compiler. You should be able to work out how to make that change, e.g. by manipulating `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: Tried with no luck. Code seems really broken, tried to build into a container as posted here https://github.com/mdedonno1337/docker-NFIQ2 with no luck,